# Uniformly integrable martingales and stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times, uniform-integrability

I want to prove the statement below:

Theorem: Let $(Y_n,\mathfrak{F})$ be a uniformly integrable martingale. Show that $(Y_{T\wedge n},\mathfrak{F})$ is a uniformly integrable martingale for any finite stopping time $T$.

I can use [Doob's optional stopping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem#Statement_of_theorem) and that a random variable which is in $L^1$ is uniformly integrable (At least I think that this two theorems are useful here..)

Doob's stopping theorem yields that $Y_T$ is integrable too and we have $\mathbb E(X_T)=\mathbb E(X_0)$.

But I need some help from here.

I appreciate any kind of help.

Edit: Since stopped martingales are martingales, we just have to show that $(Y_{T\wedge n})$ is uniformly integrable.

Answer (score 3):

Start from the equality 
$$\mathbb E[|Y_{T\wedge  n}|\mathbb 1\{|Y_{T\wedge  n}|\gt R\}  ]
=\mathbb E[|Y_{T\wedge  n}|\mathbb 1\{|Y_{T\wedge  n}|\gt R\}\mathbb 1\{T\gt n   \} ]+\mathbb E[|Y_{T\wedge  n}|\mathbb 1\{|Y_{T\wedge  n}|\gt R\}\mathbb 1\{T\leqslant n   \} ],$$
which gives 
$$\mathbb E[|Y_{T\wedge  n}|\mathbb 1\{|Y_{T\wedge  n}|\gt R\}]\leqslant \mathbb E[|Y_{ n}|\mathbb 1\{|Y_{  n}|\gt R\}  ] +\mathbb E[|Y_{T}|\mathbb 1\{|Y_{T}|\gt R\}].
$$
Since $(Y_{n\wedge T})_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a martingale and $Y_{n\wedge T}\to Y_T$ almost surely, the martingale convergence theorem shows that $Y_T$ has a finite expectation.

Comment: Cant we just estimate both addends in the last line with $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ because $Y_n$ is uniformly integrable?

Comment: Yes, that's indeed the point of the last line inequality.

Comment: But why we need the martingal convergence theorem? I thought we just need the inequality $\mathbb E[|Y_{T\wedge  n}|\mathbb 1\{|Y_{T\wedge  n}|\gt R\}]\leqslant \epsilon $ for all $\epsilon>0$ and some $R$. Thats the definition I know for uniformly integrability.

Comment: Yes, but we have to be sure that the expectation of $Y_T$ is finite in order to control the second term.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo For the stopped martingale $M_{T \land t}$, in order to use the martingale convergence theorem, I need to know that this is $L^1$ bounded. How can I see that this $L^1$ bounded?